# CodeIgniter send email redirects me to '//sendmail/'

Tags: codeigniter

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * @property mixed email
*/
class Main extends CI_Controller {
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('main_page');
}
public function sendmail()
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));

    $this->email->phone($this->input->post('phone'));
    $this->email->send();
    if($this->email->send()){
        echo 'Send!';
        redirect '/';
    }else{
        echo 'Not send!';
    }
}
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php echo form_open('/sendmail'); ?>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" />
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" />
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

here is my code from CI documentation, I did everything as it was written there. 
when I click the button submit, it redirects me to there - '//sendmail/'

Comment: what is `$this->email->phone()`?

Comment: so, my answer should be valid. You're omitting the controller

Comment: what do u mean by omitting?

Comment: read my answer below

Comment: nothing changed, it just redirects me to 'main/sendmail'

Comment: and? is what you're telling to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `echo form_open('main/sendmail');`. What happened is that you forgot the controllers name